# InvalidOperationException when calling Transaction.Current

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, transactionscope, system.transactions

I have code inside my DatabaseClient class that checks whether or not there is an active TransactionScope by examining the ThreadStatic property, Transaction.Current:

```
if (Transaction.Current == null)
{
    // open a new connection and do things
}
```

I have code consuming this class that creates a TransactionScope, executes two database operations, and then completes it. The application then moves on to do further database work. But now when it calls the code above, I get an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The current TransactionScope is already complete.
```

What do I need to do in order to "reset" the current transaction so that I can check Transaction.Current safely again?

Comment: TransactionScope.Current ? I am not aware of any static method or property on the [TransactionScope class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx). Could you explain what is TransactionScope in your code?

Comment: @Steve that was a typo... it's [System.Transactions.Transaction.Current](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.current).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a transaction has been rolled back or committed, it can't be reused. Create a new one.

Some sample code here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=netframework-4.7